# Hybrid-Search Architecture for E-Commerce Website

Tags: django, postgresql, elasticsearch, search, architecture

My question might be a little vague, but I am asking for best practice when it comes down to setting a search architecture for e-commerce website.

Our current, relevant stack consists of;

- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)/Python/DRF for the Backend
- [Vue3](https://vuejs.org/) for the Frontend

At the moment, all our search is done via [TypeSense](https://typesense.org/) (think Elasticsearch, but less bloated) search engine, that is populated from `Postgres` database.

We have lots of `Records` (Django model) entries in the database and those records can have a lots of different attributes. Instead of `EAV` structure, we solved this by simply putting all those attributes into `json` field on the model.

```
from django.db.models import JSONField

class Record(BaseModel, NonDeletableMixin):
    ... other fields
    attributes = JSONField(default=dict, blank=True, null=True)`
```

Now, there are few requirements that we have.

1. We want to support faceted search, but only for a small subset of `Record` attributes - Record Overview Page
2. We also want to be able to search through all attributes in `json` field - Search Page

The question and the problem we are having is that we don't want to implement search functionality twice, once for `TypeSense` and once for `Postgres`.

1. Postgres allowed precice search in `json` field but does not offer faceted search.
2. Typsense does offer faceted search, but in order to be able to search through all attributes, we would need to dump all the attributes into `TypeSense` engine which seems wrong.

**QUESTION: Is implementing search functionality twice good architecture or is there a better / hybrid way of doing this?**

Comment: _"but in order to be able to search through all attributes, we would need to dump all the attributes into TypeSense engine which seems wrong"_ -  why does it seem wrong?